# Retrieving python script output when connected to a Diginet device via ssh using jsch

Tags: java, ssh, jsch

I am connecting to a Digi Transport WR21 router using jsch's ChannelExec and if I execute a command, say "modemstat ?" I can capture the results but if I try to run a python script, say "python hello.py" all I get back is "OK" and the channel then closes before I can capture the output from the script.  Does anybody know how to get the python scripts output?

the command code:

```
private void sendCommand(String ipAddress, String aCommand) {
    JSch jsch = new JSch();

    try {
        Session session = jsch.getSession("username", ipAddress, 22);
        session.setPassword("password");

        java.util.Properties config = new java.util.Properties(); 
        config.put("StrictHostKeyChecking", "no");
        session.setConfig(config);

        session.connect(3*1000);

        Channel channel = session.openChannel("exec");
        ((ChannelExec) channel).setCommand(aCommand);

        channel.setInputStream(System.in);
        InputStream in = channel.getInputStream();

        channel.connect(3*1000);    
        StringBuilder commandOut = new StringBuilder();

        byte[] tmp = new byte[1024];
        while (true) {
            while (in.available() > 0) {
                int i = in.read(tmp, 0, 1024);
                if (i < 0)break;
                //System.out.print(new String(tmp, 0, i));
                //System.out.println(channel.getInputStream().toString());
                commandOut.append(new String(tmp, 0, i));

                //setChanged();
                //notifyObservers(System.err.toString() + "\n");
            }
            if (channel.isClosed()) {
                System.out.println("exit-status: "
                + channel.getExitStatus());
                break;
            }
            try {
                Thread.sleep(1000);
            } catch (Exception ee) {
                throw new JSchException("Cannot execute remote command: " + aCommand + " : " + ee.getMessage());
            }
        }

        channel.disconnect();
        session.disconnect();

        System.out.println(commandOut);


    } catch (JSchException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    } catch (IOException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

When run from the command line, the script hello.py first outputs "OK" then about a second later it outputs "Hello World".

Comment: Does this script outputs anything if you start it from the shell?

Comment: Yes.  The hello.py script first outputs "OK" then about a second later "Hello World".  The time delay is because of the way python is implemented on the box (it seems to spin a thread off to process the script).

Answer (score 1):

The answer is two fold.  Part one is that I was missing "\r\n" from the end of my command, thus "python hello.py" should have been "python hello.py\r\n".  Part two is that I needed to be using a ChannelShell instead of a ChannelExec.